# Como cambiar de branch de otro remote

Tags: git

Tengo a continuación lo que muestra git remote, y en ambos lados tengo un branch llamado main, pero me gustaría pasar a la rama main que tengo en origin (el de github ) y no en heroku, que comandos debería usar para pasar a la branch main que tengo en github

[image: muestra git remote]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiarte a cualquier rama, incluso remota:

```
git checkout origin/main
```

El problema es que si lo haces de esa forma, git no va a crear una rama local si quieres hacer operaciones (cosa que es *perfectamente* válida y posible). Si quieres que arranque una rama `main` local a partir de esa rama remota, tendrías que especificarlo en el checkout ya que solo indicando `main` al hacer checkout (si la rama no existe localmente), git no tiene una sino 2 ramas remotas que tienen ese nombre así que el checkout fallaría (insisto, si no hay una rama local con ese nombre):

```
git checkout -b main origin/main
```